# Determining 13 random numbers given MAE of more than 13 guesses as to those 13 numbers

Tags: statistics

If you are trying to find 13 random numbers and are allowed to guess all 13 at a time and are then told the mean absolute value of your error, is there a way to determine the 13 correct numbers if you have more than 13 such guesses? By mean absolute error I mean that if one guess is off by 100, another off by 50, another off by -75, then their MAE would be 75. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can binary search for the lowest number by exponentially amplifying the negative increment for your guess for the lowest number, and setting the guesses for your other numbers to be the same, and then when the MAE increases by 13 times your increment, you know your guess for the lowest number is lower than the actual value of the lowest number. So then you can binary search to find the actual value of the lowest number, it is the largest value $x$ where the difference in MAE between $x$ and $x-1$ is 13. Then once you know the lowest number, repeat the same procedure to find the second lowest number, and so forth. This might not be the optimal number of guesses, but the number of guesses is essentially $O(n \log N)$ where you have $n$ numbers and the largest absolute value of your numbers is $N$.